# How to catch parse errors in Lucerne (common lisp)

Tags: json, rest, parsing, common-lisp, clos

I'm trying to build a simple rest api in Lucerne, but the clack:call method fails if the json is malformed.  So, I extended the bass-app class and added an around method:

```
(defclass tracker-app (base-app) ()
  (:documentation "An extension of lucerne's base app to control behavior"))

(defmethod clack:call :around ((app tracker-app) env)
  (handler-case (call-next-method)

    (fast-http:cb-message-complete (e)
      (vom:error "could not build message body: ~a" e)
      (respond nil :status 400))

    (:no-error (res) res))) 

(defapp server :class 'tracker-app)

(start server :server woo)
```

But the parse error continues to crash the server.

I don't know much about clos, so I'm worried I've misunderstood how to catch errors in this context.

[image: stack trace]

Edit: Added start information

Edit: Added stack trace

Comment: I think that a bit more detail is needed.  How do you build your app (which middlewares), and what is your handler?

Comment: thanks, I've added that information.  I'm using no middleware right now for simplicity (could that be used to fix this problem) and the server is woo.  The problem happens before the route is dispatched so I'm leaving that out.

Comment: I don't know where `clack:call` comes into play and I'm too lazy to try it out.  As far as I remember, woo uses asynchronous request handling.  Your error might therefore happen in a different thread.  Have you tried a different server?

Comment: I checked the error stack, both for the Lucernes base app and my extention and clack:call is in both

Comment: Maybe show the error stack?  Include the arguments/locals if possible.

Comment: I hope that helps.  I see both clack calls, so I'm really confused why my error handling isn't working

Comment: You didn't file an issue to Lucerne's bug tracker, did you?

Comment: My assumption was  that this wasn't a bug so much as a misunderstanding on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `*features*` does not contain `:catch-any-error`, here is a complete test case:

```
(ql:quickload :lucerne)
(defpackage :so.lucerne (:use :cl :lucerne))
(in-package :so.lucerne)

(defclass tracker-app (base-app) ()
  (:documentation "An extension of lucerne's base app to control behavior"))

(defmethod clack:call :around ((app tracker-app) env)
  (handler-case (call-next-method)
    (fast-http:cb-message-complete (e)
      (warn "could not build message body: ~a" e)
      (respond nil :status 400))
    #+catch-any-error
    (error (e) (break "BREAK with ~a" e))
    (:no-error (res) res))) 

(defmethod clack:call ((app tracker-app) env)
  (error "Oh No"))

(defapp server :class 'tracker-app)
(start server :server :woo)
```

When I try to load `localhost:8000`, the following error is shown:

```
Callback Error: the message-complete callback failed
  Oh No
   [Condition of type FAST-HTTP.ERROR:CB-MESSAGE-COMPLETE]
```

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on `[Condition of type FAST-HTTP.ERROR:CB-MESSAGE-COMPLETE]` gives:

```
#<FAST-HTTP.ERROR:CB-MESSAGE-COMPLETE {10048315C3}>
--------------------
The object is a CONDITION of type FAST-HTTP.ERROR:CB-MESSAGE-COMPLETE.
FORMAT-CONTROL: NIL
FORMAT-ARGUMENTS: NIL
DESCRIPTION: "the message-complete callback failed"
ERROR: #<SIMPLE-ERROR "Oh No" {1004831583}>
```

The error wraps another error.

Now if I `(push :catch-any-error *features*)` and recompile the above method, the same test makes the code reach the `(break ...)` statement, which is shown as `BREAK with Oh No`.

#### Explanation

No `fast-http:cb-message-complete` is caught, and in fact no such condition is signaled at this point; instead at this location we only can catch the specific error that was signaled. It is only *higher up in the call stack* that errors are wrapped inside `fast-http:cb-message-complete` errors.

#### Solution

In your case you can directly catch `jonathan.error:<jonathan-error>` (unusual naming convention, but ok), the base class of all errors in the `jonathan` library (you could catch the specific error type, but then you risk missing some other cases).

Comment: Thats got it.  Thank you so much.  That was driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

[**This answer is wrong**: `fast-http.error:cb-message-complete` & `fast-http:cb-message-complete` seem to be the same symbol.  I am leaving it here for posterity.]

You are not handling the right condition (and in fact I'm not sure you're handling a condition which exists at all, which I'd expect the system to have warned about perhaps, although perhaps it can't).

You need to handle `fast-http.error:cb-message-complete`, but your handler specifies `fast-http:cb-message-complete`.  The first of these is a condition (defined [here](https://github.com/fukamachi/fast-http/blob/master/src/error.lisp#L83), while the second is I think implicitly define [here](https://github.com/fukamachi/fast-http/blob/master/src/fast-http.lisp#L192) and is not a condition but the name of a function I think.

A more general trick is to try to handle some much-too-general error: you will probably end up handling things you don't know how to handle, but if your handler gets invoked you know that the call stack looks like you think it does when the error is signalled.  Then you can start handling the errors you actually care about.  In this case that probably means `fast-http.error:callback-error` I think.

Comment: I already tried both those things.  If you look [here](https://github.com/fukamachi/fast-http/blob/master/src/fast-http.lisp#L8) you'll see that the contents of fast-http.error are imported so that they can be exported [here](https://github.com/fukamachi/fast-http/blob/master/src/fast-http.lisp#L8).  Thanks for the paragraph about the trick though.  If I can get this too work that's probably a better way to structure this.

Comment: @pricks: Oh, I hadn't realised they were the same symbol: I'd not read `fast-http`'s package definition well enough.  Sorry for my previous (now deleted) snarky comment.